# How to create tabs for a text editor in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

I am trying to create a basic text editor using `JTextPane`

Right now in Java and I was wondering if it is possible to create and then later on, remove tabs for multiple documents/text files.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you don't have any code to post?

Comment: I assume you mean you want to dynamically modify the tabs in something like a `JTabbedPane`, in which case the answer is yes, of course you can

Comment: @MadProgrammer cool thank you! That's the thing I was looking for! I have no idea why that did not pop up when I tried Googling it...